# Tomcat Resteasy + Jackson large Posted Json

Tags: tomcat, post, jackson, limit, resteasy

hi i have a WebApp on tomcat with Resteasy+Jackson

Some Resteasy-Functions of my webservice have parameters which are read from body. Everything woks ok.

Now i tested what happens when the client sends a never-ending stream of json data.

The result was that my tomcat got verry slow until it came to the exception

```
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.update(CipherCore.java:531)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineUpdate(AESCipher.java:248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1754)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:120)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.loadMore(Utf8StreamParser.java:172)
```

i already tried it with the tomcat config

```
<Connector maxPostSize="100">
```

but this had no effect, it seems to work only for multipart/formdata

is there a way to set a limit?